# Remove blank spaces with comma in a string in bash shell

Tags: bash

I would like to replace blank spaces/white spaces in a string with commas.

```
STR1=This is a string
```

to

```
STR1=This,is,a,string
```

Comment: Should 2 consecutive spaces be replaced by one comma?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Without using external tools:

```
echo ${STR1// /,}
```

Demo:

```
$ STR1="This is a string"
$ echo ${STR1// /,}
This,is,a,string
```

See [bash: Manipulating strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: Is there a way to force multiple spaces to be translated into a single comma (without turning to a tool like `awk`)?

Comment: @Kyle: if you have `extglob` on, you can do something like `${STR1//+( )/,}`.

Comment: perfect solution. Elegant.

Answer (score 16):

Just use sed:

```
echo "$STR1" | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

or a pure BASH substitution:

```
echo "${STR1// /,}"
```

Answer (score 13):

```
kent$  echo "STR1=This is a           string"|awk -v OFS="," '$1=$1'
STR1=This,is,a,string
```

**Note:**

if there are continued blanks, they would be replaced with a single comma. as example above shows.

Comment: This is almost certainly the answer that most people who visit this question are looking for, rather than variations on replacing a series of spaces with a series of commas.

Comment: I think this should be the best answer as the top answer also putting comma at the end if there is blank space which is not good.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
STR1="This is a string"
StrFix="$( echo "$STR1" | sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/g')"

echo "$StrFix"

**output**
This,is,a,string
```

If you have multiple adjacent spaces in your string and what to reduce them to just 1 comma, then change the `sed` to

```
STR1="This is    a    string"
StrFix="$( echo "$STR1" | sed 's/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/,/g')"

 echo "$StrFix"

**output**
This,is,a,string
```

I'm using a non-standard sed, and so have used ``[[:space:]][[:space:]]*`to indicate one or more "white-space" characters (including tabs, VT, maybe a few others). In a modern sed, I would expect`[[:space:]]+` to work as well.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
echo 'STR1=This is a string' | sed 'y/ /,/'
STR1=This,is,a,string
```

or:

```
echo 'STR1=This is a string' | tr ' ' ','  
STR1=This,is,a,string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
STR1=`echo $STR1 | sed 's/ /,/g'`
```